# Atualizar UI durante processo de print screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Tenho uma `Activity` e vários `Fragments` nela e, em um `Fragment`, tenho uma lista de imagens.

Quero que, através de um botão flutuante, ele tire print de todas as imagens sem precisar eu mesmo mudar a imagem que esta aparecendo na tela.

Fiz o código abaixo mas ele atualiza a imagem da tela somente após tirar as fotos, assim ele tira fotos repetidas(se a lista tem 6 imagens ele tira 2 fotos das 3 primeiras).

Gostaria de saber como ir atualizando a lista para tirar o print de todas as imagens de uma vez.

```
@OnClick(R.id.fab_client_screenshot)

public void printScreen() {
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.post(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           ListView list = JListaImagens.getInstance().getList();
           list.setSelection(0);
           int j = 0;
           while (j < list.getCount()) {
               int lastPosition = list.getLastVisiblePosition();
               try {
                  for (int i = 0; i < list.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++) {
                     if (list.getChildAt(i).isEnabled()) {
                         JUtil.saveScreenShot(list.getChildAt(i), "Imagem" + j + ".png");
                         j++;
                     }
                  }
               list.setSelection(lastPosition);
               Thread.sleep(1500);
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
               }
            }
        }
    });
}
```